# He is tall. Is it a proposition or not?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

A proposition is defined as a statement that is either true or false but not both. Then is the statement "He is tall" a proposition or not. Those who claim that it's not a proposition state that we don't know about the person referred to in the statement hence it is not a proposition. And those who claim that it's a proposition state that it is a declarative statement stating a fact and hence is a proposition.

Comment: See [What is a proposition? Conflicting definitions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070210/what-is-a-proposition-conflicting-definitions) as well as [Defining what a proposition is is in propositional logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606769/defining-what-a-proposition-is-is-in-propositional-logic) as well as [Is "today is Presidents' Day" a proposition, propositional function, or neither?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4415677/is-today-is-presidents-day-a-proposition-propositional-function-or-neither)

Comment: See [Indexicals](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/indexicals/): compare the statement "He is tall" with "Napoleon is tall". Grammatically they are similar but bot from the semantical point of view. We "know" who Napoleon is and we know if he is tall or not, but we do not know (without further information) to whom "he" is referring in "He is tall".

Comment: While “He is tall” can be framed as an open formula (so, not a proposition), it is more straightforwardly an atomic proposition whose truth value depends on the interpretation/axioms. Related: [Is "the dog is Batman" a proposition?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4671713/21813)